# Objective C - How does Calendar adds file attachments to events?

Tags: objective-c, eventkit

In OS X (tested in 10.8 and higher), it is possible to add a file attachment (like an email or a PDF file) in an already created or in-creation event by drag-and-dropping it into the event (EDIT: or event by selecting Add attachment/file).

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136780/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-file-to-an-ios-calender-event) was asked in 2013. According to the [Mac Developer Libary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EKCalendarItem), there is no place to store a file in `EKCalendarItem` or `EKEvent`. Still, Apple does it.

Does the Calendar app use the `notes` property in some way to store such file? Or does it upload the file to iCloud and link the file in the event to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single answer to your question. It depends on the server (Fruux, iCloud,  Exchange, Yahoo, ...), client version etc.

There is a simple answer to this: Can I attach files using the EventKit API? No, you can't. EventKit functionality is very limited. The 'notes' property maps to the (first or last? ...) [iCalendar description](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.5) property.

For iCloud and OSX server the OSX/iOS client should do [CalDAV managed attachments](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-daboo-caldav-attachments-03). For servers not supporting this, the client might inline the attachments in [iCalendar attachments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.1). But if I remember right there are also cases in which the client keeps the attachment just local and refers to it via a file: URL in the ATTACH property.

Summary: If you want to attach files to iCloud (or other CalDAV servers), you need to implement a [CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-carddav-client/).